# (google apps script) simple site request

Tags: google-apps-script

not yet experienced in GAS, tell me where the error is.
The code should show something similar (a similar algorithm in C # shows this): "{" document ": {" receipt ": {" operationType ": 1," fiscalSign ": 3522207165 .......... ..... "
It shows me "{" id ":" 5be96bfc38ded67a6285e66c "}"
Where is the mistake?

```
function shortenURL(longUrl) {

  var v1 = "9288000100076770"
  var v2 = "36326"
  var v3 = "1322455576"
  var v4 = "57100"
  var v5 = "2018-11-10T14:55" //2018-10-31T16:12:00

  var serviceUrl = "https://proverkacheka.nalog.ru:9999/v1/inns/*/kkts/*/fss/"+v1+"/tickets/"+v2+"?fiscalSign="+v3+"&sendToEmail=no&operationType=1&sum="+v4+"&date="+v5  
  var username ="+79312009126"
  var password ="780980"

  var options = {
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
    method:"get",
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload : JSON.stringify({'longUrl': longUrl }),
  };
  options.headers = {
  "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password),
  "device-id": "",
  "device-os": ""
  };

  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl, options);
  Browser.msgBox(response.getContentText())

}
```

Comment: What is `https://proverkacheka.nalog.ru`?  Is there documentation on an API?  The problem may be because of the URL that you are calling and not Apps Script.  If that is the case, then it's not really an Apps Script question.

Comment: What's the error or response?

Comment: Response - "{" id ":" 5be96bfc38ded67a6285e66c "}" But this is not something that should be. Wrote a script based on this: https://habrahabr.info/development/open-source/2037-universal-api-for-obtaining-information-on-checks.html